# Adding Namibian Dollar symbol to Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am stuck on a problem that is not big. However, I have tried some solutions but couldn't get it to work. The platform is wordpress and I just want to add "NAD" along with the $ sign on the products price. As I am selling products in Namibian Dollar so I want to add NAD with the sign, else people get confused with the $ sign and they assume its in USD. I have tried the following code which works for AUD , RM etc but doesn't work for "Namibian Dollar" . I did try to change it to "$", "Namibian dollar" and so on. But none worked.

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'AUD': $currency_symbol = 'AUD$'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding in the switch: `case 'NAD': $currency_symbol = 'NAD$'; break;` ?

Comment: Thanks alot. that worked, i was trying Namibian dollar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked

```
case 'NAD': $currency_symbol = 'NAD$'; break;
```